# Разбитие строки с именами на список

Tags: python, list

Получен список фита артистов в виде строки такого вида:

> MORGENSHTERN & SLAVA MARLOW

Как из этой строки получить список?

> ['MORGENSHTERN', 'SLAVA MARLOW']

Пробовал через split, но он пробелы считывает, и в итоге получается:

> ['MORGENSHTERN', 'SLAVA', 'MARLOW']

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=split#str.split

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно указать аргумент в функции split

```
>>> "Ваш%текст%два слова".split("%")

['Ваш', 'текст', 'два слова']
```

Так можно разбить строку в список.

Так будет выглядеть с вашей строкой:

```
>>> "MORGENSHTERN & SLAVA MARLOW".split(" & ")
['MORGENSHTERN', 'SLAVA MARLOW']
```

Надеюсь это поможет.

Comment: В шоке от себя что сам не додумался. Спасибо) Помогло

Comment: @robo.copp, если ответ вам помог, примите его (серая галка слева)